# How would I share the parameters between these 2 functions?

Tags: javascript, variables, data-structures, parameters, prototype

```js
const a = {
  method1: function(param) {
    this.param = param;
    $('span[data-count]').text('This is a parameter ' + param);
  },
  test: 10
}
var b = Object.create(a);
b.method2 = function(param) {
  this.param = param;
  $('.span2[data-count]').text('This is an another parameter ' + b.param);
}

b.method1('Orange');
b.method2('Blue');
```

```html
    <span data-count></span><br>
    <span data-count class="span2"></span>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#</script>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/o22/pen/zbrPJE)

I have an object called `a` which is a prototype of an another object called `b`. When these are executed, Each results are going to show up different tags `span` and `.span2`.

My goal is to share the `method1's parameter` to `method2` **without if statement**. I would like to assume `method1's parameter` on the screen when if `method2` has no parameter. So the result would be like;

> This is a parameter Orange // method1's result
>   This is an another parameter Orange // method2's result

If `method2` has its own parameter:

> This is a parameter Orange // method1's result
>   This is an another parameter Blue // method2's result

I've tried several ways to get any kinds of clues but no progress at all.

Is there any ways to do this?

Comment: Let me see if I understand - you want to call `b.method1("Orange")` which will produce `This is a parameter Orange` and then if you call `b.method2()` it should result in `This is an another parameter Orange` because you didn't supply a parameter, so it's using the one passed to `method1`. However, calling `b.method2("Blue")` should still result in `This is an another parameter Blue` because it has a parameter. Is this right?

Comment: @VLAZ Yes. That's what I exactly want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it can be done with a class

```js
const foo = new class {
  method1(param) {
    $(`span[data-count]`).text(`This is a parameter ${this.param = param}`)
  }
  
  method2(param = this.param) {
    $(`.span2[data-count]`).text(`This is an another parameter ${this.param = param}`)
  }
}

foo.method1('Orange');
foo.method2();
```

```html
<span data-count></span><br>
<span data-count class="span2"></span>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And so using your approach, we give `method2` a default value of `this.param`

```js
const a = {
  method1: function(param) {
    this.param = param;
    $('span[data-count]').text('This is a parameter ' + param);
  },
  test: 10
}

var b = Object.create(a);
b.method2 = function(param = this.param) {
  this.param = param;
  $('.span2[data-count]').text('This is an another parameter ' + b.param);
}

b.method1('Orange');
b.method2();
```

```html
<span data-count></span><br>
<span data-count class="span2"></span>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for crystal clear answer. But could you explain me what is `class` in the first example?

Comment: Since you're using the class only once you might as well make it an [anonymous/unnamed class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Class_expressions).

Answer (score 1):

You cam easily get what you want *without* using `if` statements. You can use the [logical OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean) to provide a fallback if no parameter was passed in. The fallback would be `this.param` which is set when either method is called, so the other one would still use the same value.

```js
const a = {
  method1: function(param) {
    param = param || this.param; //provide a fallback if `param` is falsey
    this.param = param;
    $('span[data-count]').text('This is a parameter ' + param);
  },
  test: 10
}
var b = Object.create(a);
b.method2 = function(param) {
  param = param || this.param; //provide a fallback if `param` is falsey
  this.param = param;
  $('.span2[data-count]').text('This is an another parameter ' + b.param);
}

b.method1('Orange');
b.method2(); //nothing passed in
```

```html
<span data-count></span><br>
    <span data-count class="span2"></span>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#</script>
```

Note that this will provide fallback for any *falsey* value. So if you want to intentionally pass `null`, `undefined`, `""` (empty string), or `0` you'd get the fallback.

Comment: Thank you for all helps :-)