# Adding sum of an array but getting NAN

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a working time clock that allows me to input the number of hours I study everyday and get the total. Am I using `parseInt` wrong?

```
   <html>
     <head>
      <title>Time clock</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">

     </head>
     <body>

        <h1 id="header">Time clock</h1>
        <p id="greeting"></p>
        <input type="text" id="inp"/>
        <button onclick="sumit()">Click</button>
        <p id="hours"></p>


       <script>
         greeting.innerHTML = 'How many hours have you studied?'

         function sumit(){
         let text = parseInt(document.getElementById("inp").value);
         let hours = (document.getElementById("hours"));
         let total = 0

         for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
          total += parseInt(text[i]);


        hours.innerHTML = `You have studied a total of ${text + total} hours.`

         }
          console.log(total)
          console.log(text) 
        }

       </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You're starting out with `let total =[]`  instead of `let total =0`

Comment: I changed it to 0 but still getting NaN

Answer (score 0):

The `text` variable is already defined and assigned the value of `parseInt`. So your `total += parseInt(text[i])` is trying to index a number type (e.g. `total += 123[0]`) which isn't possible. Instead, you can just do `total += text`, or you can remove the `parseInt` call when you declare `text` and then do `total += parseInt(text)`.

Answer (score 0):

With minimal changes, this should work:

```js
      function sumit() {
        let text = parseInt(document.getElementById("inp").value) || 0;
        let hours = document.getElementById("hours");
        let total = 0;

        total += text;

        hours.innerHTML = `You have studied a total of ${total} hours.`;
      }
```

## Explanation

- `parseInt` can return `NaN`, so we use the [`||` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean) to let it default to 0
- You don't need to loop over anything to sum the number

  - Even if you were looping over anything, you don't use reference indexes on numbers like you tried to do with `text[i]`
- You don't need to add `total` to `text` multiple times