# Javascript value returning not a number (NaN)

Tags: javascript, variables, nan

I have a section of code as follows:

```
var percentageTemp =((parseInt(score)/parseInt(guesses))*100);
var percentage= percentageTemp.toFixed(2);
```

`score` and `guesses` are both set to *0* at the start of the code, and are altered as the user plays the game. The code works as it should, exept if I leave `score` variable 0, I get a *NaN* output.
Why am I getting the *NaN* output when `score` *= 0*?

Comment: can you show us how score is initialised?

Comment: You should only get NaN when guesses is 0, your code will give 0 or "0.00" respectively when score is 0

Comment: you can't divide zero by zero - hence the NaN as JavaScript can't quantify  it. - http://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/0by0.html and a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/bLzsgd8q/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838301

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The code works as it should, exept if I leave score variable 0, I get a NaN output.

You shouldn't do (examples from the Node.JS REPL):

> ```
> > var score = 0; var guesses = 1; var percentageTemp =((parseInt(score)/parseInt(guesses))*100); var percentage= percentageTemp.toFixed(2); console.log(percentage)
> 0.00
> ```

If, on the other hand, you leave `guesses` at `0` then:

> ```
> > var score = 0; var guesses = 0; var percentageTemp =((parseInt(score)/parseInt(guesses))*100); var percentage= percentageTemp.toFixed(2); console.log(percentage)
> NaN
> ```

… because [it isn't possible to divide by zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero).

Comment: At least `0/0` will return `NaN`. Anything else `…/0` or `…/-0` will return `-Infinity` or `Infinity` depending on the sign of both numbers.

Comment: Oh and `Infinity/Infinity` will return `NaN` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise using a radix. parseInt(score, 10) to ensure the value doesn't get converted to hexadecimal. Also, note that javascripts handling of decimal numbers is not accurate. Try putting this in your console - (0.1 + 0.2) and see an unusual value returned - 0.30000000000000004