# Where in the IEEE 754 standard is the result of `Inf * 0` specified?

Tags: floating-point, precision, numeric, ieee-754

Section 6.1 of the IEEE 754-2019 standard states that:

> The behavior of infinity in floating-point arithmetic is derived from the limiting cases of real arithmetic with operands of arbitrarily large magnitude, when such a limit exists. Infinities shall be interpreted in the affine sense, that is: −∞ < {every finite number} < +∞.

However, in all implementations that I've used `Inf * 0 = NaN`, which seems to contradict quoted text.

Where in the IEEE 754 standard is the result of `Inf * 0` specified?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Infinity × 0 = NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841240/why-is-infinity-%c3%97-0-nan)

Comment: There is no contradiction because there is no limiting sense of Inf*0. For example if x[n] = n, then x->inf. For any a if y[n]=a/n then y->0. But x[n]*y[n] = a so x*y->a.

Comment: If y[n] = 0 * n, then y -> 0. What's wrong with that reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IEEE 754-2008 7.2 says:

> The invalid operation exception is signaled if and only if there is no usefully definable result. In these cases
> the operands are invalid for the operation to be performed.
>
> For operations producing results in floating-point format, the default result of an operation that signals the invalid operation exception shall be a quiet NaN that should provide some diagnostic information (see 6.2). These operations are:
>
> …
> b) multiplication: multiplication(0, ∞) or multiplication(∞, 0)
> …

A near final draft of 754-2019 is identical in the parts quoted above.

Comment: Thank you very much!