# scipy interp1d cannot handle infinite number

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a function that is `y = ax + b` where a and b are constants. I want to find out the maximum value of y. We know that if `a = 0` then `y = b`, otherwise the maximum value of y is infinity. So I tried to use scipy.interpolate.interp1d to get the answer. Running the example 2 below will result in an error message.

```
from scipy import interpolate
import math

# example 1 (works): y = x + 0
func1 = interpolate.interp1d([1,2], [1,2], fill_value='extrapolate')
print(func1(math.inf)) # this will print inf as expected

# example 2 (doesn't work): y = 1
func2 = interpolate.interp1d([1,2], [1,1], fill_value='extrapolate')
print(func2(math.inf)) # I'm expecting 1, however it showed array(nan)
```

Error message:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  y_new = slope*(x_new - x_lo)[:, None] + y_lo
```

Edit:
Replacing math.inf with a very large number, like `func2(9223372036854775807)` works too.

Comment: The problem is not that `interp1d` cannot handle an infinite number.  You disproved that in the first case, which worked just fine.  The issue is that the line has a slope of 0.  It's asymptotic in x.  There's no way for it to choose new points to extrapolate. I'd argue that this is a case of "Don't Do That".

Comment: Please see my edit regarding slope of 0

Answer (score 3):

This is due to rules for doing arithmetic with `inf` as defined in the the IEEE 754 standard. The rules are:

1. For any `x > 0`, we have `x * inf -> inf`
2. `0 * inf = nan`
3. For any `x < 0`, we have `x * inf -> -inf`

The reasons for rule 2 are discussed [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841240/why-is-infinity-%c3%97-0-nan).

If we inspect the line of code from your error message we can figure out what is going on:

```
y_new = slope * (x_new - x_lo)
```

The term in brackets has the value `inf` for both of your examples. In you first example `slope = 1` so we apply the first rule and get `1 * inf -> inf`. However, in your second example `slope = 0` so we have to use the second rule and we get `0 * inf -> nan`.

Comment: Good catch.  I didn't notice that.