# Why does the divide portion make the outshow as NaN

Tags: javascript

my code below works to add all the values together and displays the total, when I try an divide the items (/ val.flowers) it outputs NaN.

```
trimPerFlowerA(){        
        let lineA = this.model.processed.filter(val => val.originatingLine === 'A');
            if(lineA.length > 0)
               return lineA.map(val => { 
                   return (val.trimA+val.trimB+val.trimC+val.flowerOilGrade/val.flowers)
                   }).reduce((a,b) => a+b,0);
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing `lineA`.

Comment: It would suggest that `val.flowers` is zero or undefined.

Comment: Or not a number or can't be parsed as number

Comment: It means that one of the things involved in the calculation is the value `NaN` or is a non-number that, when implicitly parsed, can't be parsed as a number. At that point, since any math operation on `NaN` results in `NaN`, it spreads throughout the computation. The only way to know why that is is to look at the values in the variables. Set a breakpoint on it, and check them.

Comment: @John - If it were zero, the result would be `Infinity`, not `NaN`. (JavaScript handles divide by zero by using `Infinity`.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder. Thanks for the heads-up. I am not especially happy that a divide by zero is represented as Infinity but these answers are slightly reassuring. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838301/in-javascript-why-does-zero-divided-by-zero-return-nan-but-any-other-divided-b

Answer (score 0):

If I were to place a bet, I would say that you have some `undefined` lurking around.

This problem really depends on your input data and therefore on the contents of `this.model.processed`.
On a general basis, a number of calculations in JavaScript can result in `NaN`.

Some typical cases are:

- "A"/0
- "A"/"B"
- 0/"A"
- 0/0
- NaN/0
- 0/NaN
- NaN/NaN
- undefined/10
- 1/undefined

However, in your specific case it's also possible that the problem is not in the division but in the sum within the `(val.trimA+val.trimB+val.trimC+val.flowerOilGrade/val.flowers)` expression.
In particular, you can have `NaN` also for:

- NaN+1/10
- undefined+1

And all similar expressions.

I would recommend putting some breakpoints around and verify the individual values. If the amount of entries doesn't lend itself to breakpoints, try and put some `console.log` on those same values and then check them. This should allow you to pinpoint the specific value (or values) that cause the output to be `NaN`.

Also, once you found the issue, you will probably want to cover your base by adding unit tests working against both valid and invalid input data.