# Getting an NaN error - Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im getting an `NaN` error in the total grade. Can someone help me to find the cause of this error? Or give me some ideas how to fix this? Im just new to javascript and web development. Sorry for the logic of my code..

[image]

here's my code.

```
              function Calculate(){
                var term = $("#term").val();
                var fac_code = $("#faculty_code").val();
            $.ajax({    
              type: 'POST',                                  
              url: 'getrecords.php',                        
              data: {
                "done": 1,
                "term": term,
                "fac_code": fac_code

              },                       
              dataType: 'json',                  
              success: function(data)         
              {
                var major = data[3];              
                var quizzes = data[4];    
                var homework = data[5];      
                var attendance = data[6]; 
                var laboratory = data[7];  
                var activity = data[8];  
                var recitation = data[9];


              var q = +(document.getElementById('quiz').textContent);
              var a = +(document.getElementById('atten').textContent);
              var h = +(document.getElementById('home').textContent);
              var r = +(document.getElementById('reci').textContent);
              var m = +(document.getElementById('me').textContent);
              var ac = +(document.getElementById('activityy').textContent);
              var l = +(document.getElementById('laboratory').textContent);

              var ma = $('.me');
              var qui = $('.quize');
              var homesea = $('.hos');
              var re = $('.recits');
              var laborat = $('.labo');
              var activit = $('.activity');
              var attenda = $('.atte');

              var MisVisible = ma.is(':visible');
              var QisVisible = qui.is(':visible');
              var HisVisible = homesea.is(':visible');
              var RisVisible = re.is(':visible');
              var LisVisible = laborat.is(':visible');
              var AisVisible = activit.is(':visible');
              var ATisVisible = attenda.is(':visible');

                var mt;
                var qt;
                var ht;
                var rt;
                var act;
                var lt;
                var att;

                if (MisVisible === true) {

                  mt = m / 100 * 50 + 50;

                } 
                if (QisVisible === true){

                 qt = q / 100 * 50 + 50;

                }
                if(HisVisible === true){

                 ht = h / 100 * 50 + 50;

                }
                if(RisVisible === true){

                  rt = r / 100 * 50 + 50;
                }
                if(LisVisible === true){

                  lt = l / 100 * 50 + 50;   
                }
                if(AisVisible === true){

                  act = ac / 100 * 50 + 50;

                }
                if(ATisVisible === true){

                    att = a / 100 * 50 + 50;
                }




                  mtt = mt * (major * 0.01);
                  qtt = qt * (quizzes * 0.01);
                  attt = att * (attendance * 0.01);
                  htt = ht * (homework * 0.01);
                  rtt = rt * (recitation * 0.01);
                  actt = act * (activity * 0.01);
                  ltt = lt * (laboratory * 0.01);

          var grade = mtt + qtt + attt + htt + rtt + actt + ltt;

          document.getElementById('td_grade').innerHTML = grade;




              } 
            });
        }
```

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215120/why-javascript-says-that-a-number-is-not-a-number

Comment: Javascript is type strict. Something from html can be a string. Use parseInt or parseFloat to ensure certain number.

Comment: NaN means Not-A-Number, make sure to check all your variables if you are getting your desired values. You can use console.log(variable_name) to watch your variables.

Comment: @jomsk1e where should i put that sir?

Comment: You can put this on any line to check the current value of your variable, example: mtt = mt * (major*0.01);console.log(mtt); And use chrome's dev tool by pressing f12 and click console tab.

Comment: The mt is undefined..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Chrome's Dev tool by pressing F12 and go to console tab, to check for any variable you can use:

```
console.log(variable_name);
```

Additionally, your HTML value maybe not in a form of int so you should not use unary plus to get the value, use this instead to check whether your value is good:

```
if (!isNaN(parseFloat("10000")){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: The problem is `if (MisVisible === true)` this statement. I changed it to 0 and the result is no `NaN`..

Comment: In that case you can add else with that condition: else { mt = 0; } so that you are sure that mt will have a value when you use it with your calculation.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer would be to know how to use the Dev Tools source pane. Put breakpoints in your code, and start stepping through the code to see the values.

If I were to take a wild guess, one of these is `undefined` or missing.

```
var major = data[3];              
var quizzes = data[4];    
var homework = data[5];      
var attendance = data[6]; 
var laboratory = data[7];  
var activity = data[8];  
var recitation = data[9];
```

Or one of these can't be parsed correctly by the unary `+` as a number

```
var q = +(document.getElementById('quiz').textContent);
var a = +(document.getElementById('atten').textContent);
var h = +(document.getElementById('home').textContent);
var r = +(document.getElementById('reci').textContent);
var m = +(document.getElementById('me').textContent);
var ac = +(document.getElementById('activityy').textContent);
var l = +(document.getElementById('laboratory').textContent);
```

Comment: i'll check the data.

Comment: There is no missing or undefined in `json` data sir.