# how to add a default value to a javascript function variable?

Tags: javascript, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a better way to do optional function parameters in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148901/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript)
>   [Default value for function parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672084/default-value-for-function-parameter)

I can I do this on javascript (jQuery) function

```
function somename(variableone = "content"){
 return variableone;
}
```

Now to access that function:

```
alert(somename()) //this should alert "content"
alert(somename("hello world"); //this should return "hello world"
```

but I get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`

If this is not possible, is there a way to achieve the same result? OR most importantly is this a good (correct) practice.

Comment: dam, I searched for some time around stachoverflow and could not find that, Sorry

Comment: Obviously it is not possible, otherwise you wouldn't get a syntax error ;)

Comment: Trust me, we wish it were that simple, but it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function somename(variableone){
    if(typeof variableone === "undefined")
        variableone = "content"
    return variableone;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function somename(variableone) {
    variableone = arguments.length < 1 ? "content" : variableone;
    return variableone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a condition:

```
function somename(variableone){
    if (typeof(variableone) === "undefined") {
        variableone = "content";
    }
    return variableone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function someName(somevar){

  somevar = somevar || "content";

  console.log(somevar);

}

someName();
```

This will set somevar to itself if it is not undefined, or (|| is or) "content".

Answer (score 0):

```
function somename(variableone){
    return variableone = variableone ? variableone  : 'content'
}
```