# JS: functions arguments default values

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

In some languages you can set default values for function's arguments:

```
function Foo(arg1 = 50, arg2 = 'default') {
    //...
}
```

How do you do it in JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a better way to do optional function parameters in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148901/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In JavaScript, anything that isn't set is given the value `undefined`. This means that if you want to set default values for a function, your first line needs to be a check to see if those values aren't defined:

```
function Foo(arg1, arg2) {
    if (typeof(arg1) === "undefined") { arg1 = 50; }
    if (typeof(arg2) === "undefined") { arg2 = "default"; }
}
```

You can take a bit of a short cut if you know roughly what those values will be:

```
function Foo(arg1, arg2) {
    arg1 = arg1 || 50;
    arg2 = arg2 || "default";
}
```

However, if those arguments are falsy, they'll be replaced. This means that if arg1 is an empty string, `null`, `undefined`, `false` or `0` it'll be changed to 50, so be careful if you chose to use it

Answer (score 5):

I prefer the `== null` check instead of `typeof(arg1) === undefined` (as the jQuery library does internally: http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_Core_Style_Guidelines#JSLint). Not only is it more concise, it also handles both null and undefined, so that client code can pass in `null` and get the default applied.

It is also possible to wrap the function in another function that supplies defaults. The prototypejs library has a function that supplies the `argumentNames()` (or if you don't want to use prototype, you can just borrow the implementation -- it's just a regex applied against the results of the function's `toString()`).

So you could do something like this:

```
var Foo = defaults(Foo, { arg1: 50, arg2: 'default' });
function Foo(arg1, arg2) {
  //...
}
```

And the implementation of `defaults()` would look something like this:

```
function defaults(fn, def) {
  return function() {
    var arg_names = fn.argumentNames();
    var nArgs = args.length;
    for (var nArg = 0; nArg < nArgs; ++nArg) {
      if (arguments[nArg] == null && arg_names[nArg] in def)
        arguments[nArg] = def[arg_names[nArg]];
    }
    fn.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}
```

Of course, that's untested code and the way it's written, it requires the Prototype library. But all that said, the `== null` approach inside the function is more natural to Javascript, is easier to debug (you don't have another function layer to step through), and I find it easier to read:

```
function Foo(arg1, arg2) {
  if (arg1 == null) arg1 = 50;
  if (arg2 == null) arg2 = 'default';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. By the way jQuery guidelines requires braces to be used in blocks. I prefer this too. So I guess something like `arg1 == null && arg1 = 50` would be correct (i'm not sure about operators priority in JS)?

Answer (score 2):

As of ES2015 (ES6), default parameters can be set like so:

```
function multiply (a, b = 2) {
  return a * b;
}
multiply(5); // 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do it in the function body:

```
function Foo(arg1 ,arg2) {
    if( typeof arg1 === 'undefined' )
        arg1 = 50;

    if( typeof arg2 === 'undefined' )
        arg2 = 'default';
    //...
}
```

Another way to test them for `undefined` or `null` is like this:

```
function Foo(arg1 ,arg2) {
    if( arg1 == undefined )
        arg1 = 50;

    if( arg2 == undefined )
        arg2 = 'default';
    //...
}
```

Some people don't like it because it is possible to override the value of `undefined` since it is just a global property. As long as it isn't overridden, this would work fine. If the parameters are `null` or `undefined`, they'll be set to a default.