# how to write a js function with changing number of paramets parameters

Tags: javascript, html, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript variable number of arguments to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141520/javascript-variable-number-of-arguments-to-function)
>   [JS: functions arguments default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771330/js-functions-arguments-default-values)

I want to write this sort of function that accepts various number of parameters like this:

```
PopupBox.init() //Creating a pop up box with a default height and width of 100px
PopupBox.init(50px) //Creating a popup with height and width of 50px
PopupBox.init(50px,100px) //Creating a popup with the height 50px and width 100px
```

My question is how do I write the function itself?
I would have tried something like this but I assume it won't work. how do I write it correctly so the function can receive multiple parameters?

```
var PopupBox = {
    init :function (width,height) {
        if (height == null) {
           height=100px;
        }
        if (width == null) {
           height=100px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've written the code. Why not test it instead of assuming it won't work?

Comment: I thought that there is not a chance that it would work - I only gave this code as an example. but once tested it - it did work! but why? how can it take multiple parameters like that?

Comment: Any argument that has a placeholder but isn't passed a value gets `undefined`.