# Angular JS Android app Unexpected token for default parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, debugging, mobile

when running the app that I have build on angular/phonegap I get the following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

The error is caused by the default value supplied for the parameter.But why is that?It works perfectly fine on a few devices and throws this error on others.
Here is the code:

```
.factory('foo' , function(){
  return {
   test : function(id = 0){
     console.log(id);
   }
  }
 })
```

Here is the  solution :

```
.factory('foo' , function(){
  return {
   test : function(id){
    id  = ( id !== undefined ) ? id : 0;
    console.log(id);
   }
  }
})
```

Comment: your solution has issues with values that evaluate to falsey, read this answer for more details http://stackoverflow.com/a/6486334/4963159

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) are a fairly new ECMAScript feature that was only added in the ECMAScript 2015.

The reason that it works on some devices but not others is down to the fact that they may have different browsers, or different versions of the same browser.

Only the latest browsers would be able to interpret and compile your code with ECMAScript 2015 features.

To get around this issue, if you want to use the latest specs without worrying about checking which features are available on which browsers, consider using a transpiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) in your build pipeline.