# jQuery modal created several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have **Open Modal** button and when you click button, my modal has been creating with jquery, everything is okey so far but I guess my method is wrong because I noticed a bug is after open the modal if you close and if you open again you will see it has been creating 2 times,3 times,4 times....

so where is my mistake ? and another question is how can I send my parameters default value ?

```js
function generateModal(modalTitle, modalWidth, modalHeight, iframeUrl, iframeWidth, iframeHeight) {
  var html =
    '<div class="modal fade mapModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width:' + modalWidth + ';height:' + modalHeight + '"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
  html = html + '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' + modalTitle + "</h4></div>";
  html = html + '<div class="modal-body"><iframe src="' + iframeUrl + '" width="' + iframeWidth + '" height="' + iframeHeight + '" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
  html = html + "</div></div></div>";

  $(document.body).append(html);
  $(".mapModal").modal();
}


$(document).on("click", ".open-modal", function() {
  generateModal("Modal deneme ", "60%", "500px", "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m10!1m8!1m3!1d12047.436573933934!2d29.098413750000002!3d40.984565100000005!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1str!2str!4v1463140023736", "100%", "auto");
});
```

```css
.open-modal {
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ccc;
}

.open-modal:hover {
  background: #050505;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #000;
}

.modal-dialog iframe {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p class="open-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".mapModal" aria-expanded="false">Open Modal</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/PjYXwo)

Comment: You never remove `.mapModal` when closing it i guess.

Comment: oooh I'm trying now thank you!

Comment: $(document.body).append(html); here you are append html into body  tag while closing a model  you did't delete the html tag properly  then again your trying to open a new Model   $(document.body).append(html); again it will happen here  so twice its opening

Comment: @Arg0n you are correct he did't remove .mapModal while closing a model thats why two,threee models show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because every time it is clicked it creates a new modal box so check your modal length and create if it is not created before like,

```js
function generateModal(modalTitle, modalWidth, modalHeight, iframeUrl, iframeWidth, iframeHeight) {
  var html =
    '<div class="modal fade mapModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width:' + modalWidth + ';height:' + modalHeight + '"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
  html = html + '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' + modalTitle + "</h4></div>";
  html = html + '<div class="modal-body"><iframe src="' + iframeUrl + '" width="' + iframeWidth + '" height="' + iframeHeight + '" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
  html = html + "</div></div></div>";
  // check length and append if it is not added before
  !$(".mapModal").length && $(document.body).append(html);
  $(".mapModal").modal();
}


$(document).on("click", ".open-modal", function() {
  generateModal("Modal deneme ", "60%", "500px", "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m10!1m8!1m3!1d12047.436573933934!2d29.098413750000002!3d40.984565100000005!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1str!2str!4v1463140023736", "100%", "auto");
});
```

```css
.open-modal {
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ccc;
}

.open-modal:hover {
  background: #050505;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #000;
}

.modal-dialog iframe {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p class="open-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".mapModal" aria-expanded="false">Open Modal</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

For the default values you can check parameters in your function like,

```js
function generateModal(modalTitle, modalWidth, modalHeight, iframeUrl, iframeWidth, iframeHeight) {
  modalTitle = modalTitle || 'Default Modal Name';
  modalWidth = modalWidth || '80%';
  modalHeight = modalHeight || '500px';
  iframeUrl = iframeUrl || 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m10!1m8!1m3!1d12047.436573933934!2d29.098413750000002!3d40.984565100000005!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1str!2str!4v1463140023736'
  iframeWidth = iframeWidth || '100%';
  iframeHeight = iframeHeight || '100%';
  
  var html =
    '<div class="modal fade mapModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width:' + modalWidth + ';height:' + modalHeight + '"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
  html = html + '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' + modalTitle + "</h4></div>";
  html = html + '<div class="modal-body"><iframe src="' + iframeUrl + '" width="' + iframeWidth + '" height="' + iframeHeight + '" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
  html = html + "</div></div></div>";
  $(document.body).append(html);
  $(".mapModal").modal().on('hidden.bs.modal',function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });
}


$(document).on("click", ".open-modal", function() {
  generateModal("Modal deneme ", "60%", "500px", "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m10!1m8!1m3!1d12047.436573933934!2d29.098413750000002!3d40.984565100000005!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1str!2str!4v1463140023736", "100%", "auto");
});
$(document).on("click", ".open-modal-default", function() {
  generateModal();
});
```

```css
.open-modal,.open-modal-default {
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ccc;
}

.open-modal:hover,.open-modal-default:hover {
  background: #050505;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #000;
}

.modal-dialog iframe {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p class="open-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".mapModal" aria-expanded="false">Open Modal</p>
<p class="open-modal-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".mapModal" aria-expanded="false">Open Modal Default</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it's great example thank you so much so I searched before you write and I see this code for default parameters  `function name(arg=false,arg2="string",arg3=12){}` are they same thing?

Comment: Yes you can, also you can look for the answers given on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486307/default-argument-values-in-javascript-functions

Answer (score 2):

You generate a new modal each time you click the button. If you could add a handler that gets executed once the modal is closed again, then you can fix it by simply removing the element.

You could use jQuery's `.remove()`-function (notice that your modal needs an ID for that to work correctly).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `append` you can use `.html()`.

```
$('<modal selector>').html(html);
$(".mapModal").modal();
```

Or you can remove last appended div using `.remove()`

```
$('body .mapModal').remove();
$(document.body).append(html);
$(".mapModal").modal();
```

or you can use `replaceWith()`

```
if($('.mapModal').length) {
    $( ".mapModal" ).replaceWith(html);
} else {
    $(document.body).append(html);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In you case you append the `html` .so it increased each time of click .so You need add with `parent` element for whole append `html` .Then remove that `parent` element each time of click before the append html

```js
function generateModal(modalTitle, modalWidth, modalHeight, iframeUrl, iframeWidth, iframeHeight) {
  var html =
    '<div class="modal fade mapModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width:' + modalWidth + ';height:' + modalHeight + '"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
  html = html + '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' + modalTitle + "</h4></div>";
  html = html + '<div class="modal-body"><iframe src="' + iframeUrl + '" width="' + iframeWidth + '" height="' + iframeHeight + '" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
  html = html + "</div></div></div>";
$('.modal-parent').remove()
$('.modal-backdrop').fadeOut()
  $(document.body).append('<div class="modal-parent">'+html+'</div>');
  $(".mapModal").modal();
}


$(document).on("click", ".open-modal", function() {
  generateModal("Modal deneme ", "60%", "500px", "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m10!1m8!1m3!1d12047.436573933934!2d29.098413750000002!3d40.984565100000005!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1str!2str!4v1463140023736", "100%", "auto");
});
```

```css
.open-modal {
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ccc;
}

.open-modal:hover {
  background: #050505;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #000;
}

.modal-dialog iframe {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p class="open-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".mapModal" aria-expanded="false">Open Modal</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```