# Recommended way to handle required and optional function parameters

Tags: javascript, function

I have a javascript function that takes two parameters, 'key' and 'value'.

If only one parameter is given then the 'key' parameter is given a default value and the undefined 'value' parameter gets the 'key' parameter value.

```
function thingSet(key,value){
    if(typeof value === 'undefined'){
        value=key;
        key='_default';
    }
    //... use key and value
}
```

The code works but I feel abit uneasy for some reason.

Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148901/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript

Comment: @Tim I saw that but my case is slightly different with the parameter swapping...

Answer (score 2):

You can refactor it like this:

```
function thingSet (key, value) {
    key = key || '_default';
    value = value || key;
    //... use key and value
}
```

That's nice short-circuit evaluation allowing you to set default values easily there.

Comment: Thats not the expected logic. If only one parameter is given (the value) then your 'key' is set to the value - not the default.

Comment: @zaf: If that's what you are looking for and you understand the logic, you can change it to however you like but using `||` is easy way of setting defaults, that's the point here :)

Comment: You should edit the 're-factored' code and highlight your point. As it stands your function is different to the original one.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty standard and heavily used "overloading" mechanism in javascript. You'll find it all over the libraries like jQuery.

Like many dynamic language constructs, there is a gap between what compiler can check for you and what you have to keep as a convention, perhaps documenting it thouroughly.

The power comes at a price of robustness. If you use this kind of tricks, you have to make sure everybody understands the implied API and uses it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can set default values like this:

```
function thingSet(key,value){
    key = key || '_default';
    value = value || key;
    //... use key and value
}
```

At least, that is what I make of your function. The unease may be due to the fact that in your function `key` may be `undefined` too, in which case the assignment after checking the condition `if(typeof value === 'undefined')` still may result in an `undefined` `value`

You can check for existence of at least one parameter using `arguments.length`.

```
function thingSet(key,value){
    if (!arguments.length) {
       alert('please supply at least one parameter'); 
       return true;
    }
    key = key || '_default';
    value = value || key;
    //... use key and value
}
```

Comment: Thats not the expected logic. If only one parameter is given (the value) then your 'key' is set to the value - not the default.

Answer (score 0):

Seems fine to me. The only thing I'd have done differently would be a more direct comparison on value:

```
if(value == undefined){
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally do this with JSON

```
myfunction = function(args){
    args.key =  (typof(args.key) == "undefined")?args.key = "_default":args.key;
    args.value =  (typof(args.value) == "undefined")?args.key:args.value;
}

myfunction({key:"something",value:"something else"})
```

that way you know which variable you are passing to the function and don't have to assume anything from within the function.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to discuss design questions on a dummy example, but I'd prefer a function that always accepts one parameter, which can be a simple value, or a hash of values. Consider this slightly more realistic example:

```
function setName(opt) {
    if (typeof opt != "object") {
        var p = opt.split(" ");
        opt = { first: p[0], last: p[1] };
    }
    $.extend(this, opt);
}
```

This can be used as `person.setName('John Doe')` or `person.setName({last:'Doe'})`