# Javascript function with default not required values

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, arguments

I can't find the similiar problem, I guess it's because i can't find a correct question/answer.
I want to create a function that will use default values if there is not arguments passed when calling a function, if so, replace default values with the values passed in function's parameters.
For example:

```
function openBlock(false){
  // if parameter was passed with 'false' value, it will do this

  // else it will put automatically a 'true' value to an function's argument
}
```

So if call a function `openBlock()` without any params, it will consider that it's param `true` by default. If i call a function with argument `false` like `openBlock(false)` it will override the default behavior.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do this in Javascript, though none are built in. The easiest pattern is:

```
function(option) {
    option = option || "default";
    // do stuff
}
```

But as @FelixKling notes, this won't work in your case, as it will replace any false-y value (including explicitly setting the argument to `false`) with the default. For boolean arguments that you want to default to `true`, you need:

```
function(option) {
    // default to "true"
    option = option !== undefined ? option : true;
    // do stuff
}
```

When you're dealing with more than one or two arguments, the best option is often to use a single `options` or `config` argument and check for the existence of properties:

```
function(options) {
    var arg1 = option.arg1 !== undefined ? false : true;
    var arg2 = option.arg2 || "default";
    // do stuff
}
```

If you're using a library like jQuery or underscore, the `extend` method makes it quite easy to set up an object with default values and then overwrite them with supplied values if they exist:

```
function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        arg1: true,
        arg2: "default"
    };
    options _.extend(defaults, options);
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: @FelixKling - true, updated. I usually use this pattern in cases where false-y values should be replaced with a default, not for booleans.

Comment: thanks so much, i think that's exactly what i asked for, will check it out now

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't really have default parameters implemented like other languages do.

You'll have to implement them yourself:

```
function openBlock(argument) {
  argument = typeof argument !== 'undefined';
}
```

Take a look at [Is there a better way to do optional function parameters in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148901/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript) for a more generic approach.

Comment: `openBlock(true)` will be the same as `openBlock(false)` with this code.