# Is there a way to do function overloading in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that looks like this:

```
function getTopicOptions(accountID, showTitles, showSelectGroup) {
    "use strict";

    var accountID = store.getItem('AccountID');  
    showTitles = (showTitles !== 'undefined') ? showTitles : 'Y';
    showSelectGroup = (showSelectGroup !== 'undefined') ? showSelectGroup : 'Y';
```

The idea is that if showTitle and showSelectGroup are not supplied then they will get the default of "Y".

Is there a way do this with function overloading or a way to have the function parameters checked (jslint?) or a way to simplify what I need to do without the undefined check?

Comment: What type is showTitles and showSelectGroup supposed to be (if defined)? Are they functions?

Comment: showTitles and showSelectGroup are either "Y" or "N"

Comment: In this case, I'd prefer codebox's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
showTitles = showTitles || 'Y';
```

or this would work as well, but is more verbose

```
showTitles = showTitles ? showTitles : 'Y';
```

I'm not sure where function overloading comes into your question.

Comment: Note that this is a truthy condition, it will not only fail for `undefined` but also for `false` and `null`

Comment: @Alexander also `0`, `''` and `NaN`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think in this situation even if it failed with the conditions listed it would be okay as all those conditions could also be another way of not showing the title.

Comment: I like this solution a lot too when I'm expecting (and only expecting) an object to be passed. Objects in JavaScript are always truthy.

Comment: @Marilou, No offense but I think that using "Y"/"N" here instead of boolean values seems stupid

Answer (score 1):

There is popular default params trick:

```
var showSelectGroup = showSelectGroup || false;
```

but it depend on param, if it `bool` (`''`, `0` and etc) and looks like `showSelectGroup || true` you can't set `false`

Also look at:

- [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)
- [Is there a better way to do optional function parameters in
  Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148901/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Following is possible

```
var functionTest = function(argu) {
        argu = argu || 'my argument';//ifargu not passed than 'my argument'
        return argu;
};

alert(functionTest());
// browser alerts "my argument"
```

---

There is no way of function overloading in javascript ,

But if you dont pass the vlaue in function its became undefined vlaue that means you can call the function like

this function

```
getTopicOptions(accountID, showTitles, showSelectGroup)
```

can be called like

```
getTopicOptions(1);
```

other  two value becomes undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `arguments` object which is (more or less) an array of all supplied arguments. You can loop through these.

See http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/javascripts-arguments-object-and-beyond/