# Default parameter of a JavaScript function is not working when intermittent value is missing

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments, default

I have read two similar posts on the subject and tried the provided solutions to use default values for parameters in a JavaScript function.

The solutions work when the terminal or ending parameters are missing yet if one of the intermediate parameter is missing the code does not seem to work.

Any possible hint on what I am doing wrong on this would help greatly as I am starting to convert my financial functions library for JavaScript

```
var tadJS = {
tadAEY: function(r, c)
{
    if (r==0.0)
        return 0.0;
    if (c==0.0)
        return Math.exp(r) - 1;
    else
    return Math.pow(1.0+r*c, 1/c) - 1;
},
tadPVIF2: function(r, n, c, p, d)
{
  var t=0.0;
  c = (typeof c !== "undefined") ? c : 1;
  p = (typeof p !== "undefined") ? p : 1;
  d = (typeof d !== "undefined") ? d : 1;
  t = (n-1)*p+d*p;
  if (r==0.0)
     return 1.0;
  return Math.pow(1.0+this.tadAEY(r,c),-t);
}
};
```

The following call to the function returns the value when the last three parameters are missing

```
document.write( "PVIF(10%, 10, 1, 1, 1) = " + tadJS.tadPVIF2(0.10,10) );
```

The following call to the JavaScript function does not work when the third parameter is missing

```
document.write( "PVIF(10%, 10, 1, 1/2, 1) = " + tadJS.tadPVIF2(0.10,10,,0.5) );
```

The following two threads were used as a reference for the solution to default parameters in JavaScript function

[Is there a better way to do optional function parameters in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148901/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript)

[Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `,,0.5` is invalid JavaScript.

There are two simple solutions:

1. Pass `undefined` for the parameters that you are omitting:

   ```
   tadJS.tadPVIF2(0.10, 10, undefined, 0.5);
   ```
2. Optionally accept an object as the first argument:

   ```
   tadJS.tadPVIF2({r: 0.10, n: 10, p: 0.5});
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, both of your solutions are working like a charm. However I would have to make use of the first option whereby placing "undefined" for the missing values of argument. This is so as the PVIF function is used iteratively in other functions and the object interface would make it more cumbersome to code such functions.