# First line of Javascript file is var w = w || {};

Tags: javascript

This is the very first line of a JavaScript file I am modifying and and what does it do? jQuery is also used in the file.

```
var w = w || {};
```

From what I know the || is a logical operator this is a quote from the Mozilla documentation. 
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR)

> Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values. When they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the && and || operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may return a non-Boolean value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)

Comment: It checks to see if w is already defined and if not, it assigns an empty object to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a better way to do optional function parameters in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148901/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see that line as a shortened version of this.

```
// declare w as a variable
var w;

// if w is already declared, leave it
if (!w) {
  // if not make it an empty object
  w = {};
}
```

In the global context (where I'm sure this is defined), using var will not overwrite an existing global.

So basically, you are ensuring that there is a var by the name of w that you are able to store properties on.

Answer (score 2):

It sets `w` to `w`'s current value if `w` is "truthy", and `w` to an empty object if `w` is "falsy."

Falsy values include `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `empty strings`, and of course `false`.

Everything else is truthy.

Essentially, it makes sure that w is an object if it is not one already.

Comment: `{}` is not an array.

Comment: @GergoErdosi yep, I mistyped that. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It assigns w to w if it contains a value that is not false, else, it sets w as an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

This is to check if 'w' is truthy or falsy.

'w' is falsy if it has any of the values:

```
false
0
""
null
undefined
NaN
```

The expression `(w || {})` will return 'w' if it is **not** a falsy value. Otherwise, it will return an empty array. So when you assign it to 'w' in the expression: `var w = w || {};` 
It is just a way of making sure 'w' isn't a falsy value and doesn't throw any errors if it gets used later on in your code.