# Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,(class))

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Just want to create simple filler to use it in other functions:

```
function fillLine(row, column, length, bgcolor)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1+row, 1+column, 1, length).setBackground(bgcolor)
}
```

But getting: "Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,(class))".

Is it possible to create one?

*added 23.10.2014 23:32 GMT+2*

I was trying to run function itself. Option "fillLine" in run menu was checked. When I change it to my main function "onOpen" everything works. For else functions I can run them even without arguments, but not for this one. Maybe someone can explain?

Comment: Your function should work, it looks like you are passing an invalid value for length. Length should be a number.

Comment: The problem is I need to send `lenght` as agument. But even when I'm changing `lenght` to constant, for example `5` getting new error: "Can't convert NaN to (class)" @cameron-roberts

Comment: This is definitely a problem with the values you are passing to fillLine(), either row or column is also not a number.  If you call fillLine(1,1,10,'red'); it works.

Comment: `sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 1).setBackground(bgcolor)` works great. Everything else with `row column length` no.

Answer (score 4):

You're running this in the debugger with NO parameters. If you want to do that, you need to ensure you have appropriate default values defined before using the parameters, otherwise the interpreter will start making guesses.

This would fix things for you, by providing defaults if parameters are empty:

```
function fillLine(row, column, length, bgcolor)
{
  row = row || 0;
  column = column || 0;
  length = length || 1;
  bgcolor = bgcolor || "red";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1+row, 1+column, 1, length).setBackground(bgcolor)
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a test function like this, and call *it* from the debugger:

```
function test_fillLine() {
  fillLine(0, 0, 1, 'red');
}
```

There are other approaches, some described in [Is there a better way to do optional function parameters in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148901/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript)

---

So what's going on?

Javascript parameters are not explicitly typed.  Therefore, the interpreter must examine passed objects at run time to determine their type.

In this example, with no parameters passed, all are set to the `undefined` value, with the 'Undefined' type.

When a function is invoked, the interpreter needs to determine which of sometimes several signatures applies. (`Sheet.getRange` has 4 variants.) To do that, it must resolve the number and types of the parameters provided.

So, here we go...

- `1+row`, and `1+column` are identified as numbers, because the literal "1" is a number.
- `1` is clearly a number
- `length` is an Undefined Object, and without any other objects to provide hints, the interpreter thinks it is a plain `class`.

Therefore, the interpreter decides it needs to find a `getRange` method of the `sheet` object with a signature `number, number, number, class`. It doesn't find one, and throws the exception you see.

Comment: Thanks a lot for so detailed answer. I'm beginer in G-app-script and java. So such complete explanations is very helpfull for me. Thanks! @mogsdad

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded by using offset.

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
//var range = sheet.getRange(row, column, height, width)
var range = sheet.getRange('A1').offset(row - 1, column - 1, height, width)
```

So in your case, the following code may run.

```js
function fillLine(row, column, length, bgcolor) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  //var range = sheet.getRange(row, column, 1, length)
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1').offset(row - 1, column - 1, 1, length)
  range.setBackground(bgcolor)
}
```

In my case, I need to add **permission** to use setBackground.
A popup menu to add the permission appeared in a script editor when I run a test script as [@Mogsdad said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26537339/3774895).

```js
function test_fillLine() {
  fillLine(1, 1, 2, 'red');
}
```

[image]

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Thank for your advice.
I improved my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through the *activeSpreadsheet*, where the *activeSheet* is "embedded" in, i. e.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
```

intead of

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```