# 0 with || operator

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript you can make a function like this:

```
function Cat(children) {
    this.children = children || 3;
}
```

What it does is that it creates a `Cat` object with a `children` value, if you do not pass the `children` inside the function like `var mimmi = new Cat();`, it will be the same as `var mimmi = new Cat(undefined);`, which means that `mimmi` will have the default amount of `children` which is 3.

However, the only problem with this is that if I enter `0`, it will be count as `false` and `children` will be set to `3`, when I actually want it to be set to `0`.

What's the most elegant way to make a function like this but still allow for 0's?

I don't really think this is so nice looking though:

```
function Cat(children) {
    this.children = (typeof this.children == "number") ? children : 3
}
```

Comment: it's not nice looking, but it's what's required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a better way to do optional function parameters in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148901/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript)

Comment: @Juhana this is about a specific case - that question is about optional parameters in general.

Comment: Would `children >= 0 ? children : 3` be any better? Same idea as the second example, but shorter

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum This specific case falls neatly within the general case. The accepted answer even addresses the 0-case directly.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 5):

Right, there is no elegant way in ES5 to do that, you should never use `||` for default value with primitives (string, number, boolean, null and undefined) for precisely the reason you thought of.

The code you have with the `typeof` is almost correct (should check `typeof` of just children) and is correct:

```
function Cat(children) {
    this.children = (typeof children === "number") ? children : 3
}
```

In ES6 you get default parameters which make this a lot nicer:

```
function Cat(children = 3) {
    this.children = children; // requires a runtime that supports ES6
}
```

Although the more ES6 way would be to use a `class`.

Comment: Cool to see that there is a way to do this with ES6!

Comment: About the function with ES6, where do you put the `3`?

Comment: @Murplyx that was a silly mistake :D I wrote 0 instead of 3 there. Fixed now.

Comment: @Murplyx if you want to write ES6 code currently transpilation is required through TypeScript or Babel, personally I prefer Babel since it adheres to the standard more closely, doesn't impose new constructs and is easier to use in my experience (just another `script` tag).

Comment: So bad just that normal browsers like chrome doesn't support it

Comment: @Murplyx that's because Chrome are moving JS engine compilers right now (from CrankShaft to TurboFan) so it'll take a bit, once they're done transitioning features will get in very fast.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is a numerical value that you want can use `isNaN()`

```
function Cat(children) {
    this.children = isNaN(children) ? 3 : children;
}
```

Comment: Really nice case-specific answer!

Comment: Note that this has different results from OP's code if you pass `NaN` which is a number. Not that it's a big deal.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum NaN stands for "Not a Number" so NaN therefore, is not a number simply :D

Comment: @Murplyx NaN is a number, `typeof NaN` returns number, it was poorly named but you can easily get it by applying operations to numbers (for example 1/0) - see [here - "Number value"](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.23). Like I said - really not a big deal. Just a semantic difference.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that doesn't make sense , `isNaN( NaN)` returns true

Comment: @charlietfl right, because `isNaN` checks if something, when coerced to a number is `NaN` - when you coerce or convert something that is not a number to a number in JS it might be a valid number or NaN (which is still a number, since you converted it to a number) - it just represents an "invalid" number.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution which is great for doing this with multiple functions and variables:

```
function por(p, d) { // por = parameter or gate
    return ((typeof p === "undefined") ? d : p);
}
```

where `p` is the parameter and `d` is the default value.

In the Cat case, you could use this like this:

```
function Cat(children) {
    this.children = por(children, 3);
}
```

With "multiple functions and variables" I mean when you need to do it on a large scale, for example:

```
function ABC(a, b, c) {
    this.a = por(a, 1);
    this.b = por(b, 2);
    this.c = por(c, 3);
}
```

rather than:

```
function ABC(a, b, c) {
    this.a = ((typeof a === "undefined") ? 1 : a);
    this.b = ((typeof b === "undefined") ? 2 : b);
    this.c = ((typeof c === "undefined") ? 3 : c);
}
```

Comment: For discussion about this pattern see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/203469/if-my-team-has-low-skill-should-i-lower-the-skill-of-my-code

Answer (score 0):

As you have found out, 0 is a boolean value. You should be checking for an undefined value.

Try:

```js
var Cat = function(children) {
 this.children = (children === undefined) ? 3 : children;
};
```

Comment: Why a test when it's just a script without HTML