# What is the recommended way to have an optional parameter for an AngularJS function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, optional-parameters

Edit: This post [Is there a better way to do optional function parameters in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148901/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript) provides an answer to this question.

This is my controller:

```
.controller("NavTabController", ['TabService', function(TabService) {
        var self = this;

        self.switchTab = function(currentTab, dropDown) {
            TabService.switchTab(currentTab, dropDown);
        }
}])
```

and this is the factory:

```
.factory("TabService", [function() {
    var tab = "home";
    return {
        switchTab: function(currentTab, dropDown) {
            tab = currentTab;
        }
    }
}])
```

In my HTML, I have this:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.switchTab('home')">Home</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.switchTab('home', 'middle')">Optional</a>
```

As you can see, I want dropDown to be optional because sometimes it is not provided.

With that said, what is the recommended way to have an optional parameter for an AngularJS function?

Comment: You have a typo ~ `dropDown` vs `dropDrown`

Comment: @Phil you are right, that is what was causing the issue. Turns out, AngularJS automatically makes the parameter "undefined" if it isn't provided. AngularJS does not throw an error when I do not provide a parameter. I'm assuming the recommended way is to do "if (typeof optionalArg === 'undefined') { optionalArg = 'default'; }" because that is the answer for the other SO question. So I'll mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `arguments.length === 2`