# What is "[," function arguments list in javascript API's

Tags: javascript

When going through docs or API's of JS libraries, I notice a **"[,"** in params list.

Eg: vega.key(fields[, flat])

Does it mean optional arguments. How to interpret these.

Comment: Yes, these are optional arguments.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148901/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript for interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a (widely-used) notation in **documentation** (and only in documentation; it is not valid syntax).

The part `[, flat]` means the second argument is named `flat` and it is optional.

The function can be called with two arguments (`vega.key(fields, flat)`) or with only one argument (`vega.key(fields)`). In this case, the comma must also be stripped (i.e. calling it as `vega.key(fields,)` is invalid syntax.

You will also encounter this notation: `vega.key(fields[, flat, ...])` or `vega.keys(fields[, ...])` that means the function can be invoked with one or more arguments; `fields` is required in the above notation, the others are optional.

Answer (score 2):

It means optional argument. You will often see

```
someFunc(arg1[, arg2[, arg3]])
```

which means arg2 and arg3 are optional. When arg2 is passed to the function, arg3 need not be, because it's optional, but arg2 is necessary when arg3 is passed.