# How can you use arguments.length to find the number of arguments passed to a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a function that needs to determine how many arguments have been passed to itself. I am able to get this information after a function has been declared, but whenever I call it from within a function using `arguments.length`, I get the same inaccurate answer.

Example using `{function}.length` after function is declared:

```
const noParameters = () => {};
const oneParameter = (a) => {};
const twoParameters = (a, b) => {};

console.log(noParameters.length);   // 0
console.log(oneParameter.length);   // 1
console.log(twoParameters.length);  // 2
```

Example using `argument.length` within the function

```
const noArguments = () => {
  return arguments.length
}

const oneArgument = () => {
  return arguments.length
}

const twoArguments = () => {
  return arguments.length
}

console.log(noArguments());       // 5
console.log(oneArgument(1));      // 5
console.log(twoArguments(1, 2));  // 5
```

I am trying to understand the `arguments` object itself, but it doesn't seem to be related to the function it is returning. From printing `arguments` to the console, it appears to be related to the file I am running:

```
const whatIsArgument = () => {
  return arguments
}

console.log(whatIsArgument());

// Console returns: 
[Arguments] {
  '0': {},
  '1': 
   { [Function: require]
     resolve: { [Function: resolve] paths: [Function: paths] },
     main: 
      Module {
        id: '.',
        exports: {},
        parent: null,
        filename: '{redacted filepath}/test.js',
        loaded: false,
        children: [],
        paths: [Array] },
     extensions: { '.js': [Function], '.json': [Function], '.node': [Function] },
     cache: 
      { '{redacted filepath}/test.js': [Module] } },
  '2': 
   Module {
     id: '.',
     exports: {},
     parent: null,
     filename: '/{redacted filepath}/test.js',
     loaded: false,
     children: [],
     paths: 
      [ {array of all the files in my project directory } ] },
  '3': '{redacted filepath}/test.js',
  '4': '{redacted filepath}' }
```

*Note: file-paths have been redacted for privacy.*

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on here? Everything online indicated that arguments.length should return what I'm looking for, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: Arrow functions don't have an `arguments` binding, so I would expect your code to throw an error. Is your code wrapped in a function?

Comment: It will just go to the `arguments` of whatever the surrounding function is, which i think may be a requirejs function, possibly created by a build process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `arguments` object is the old-fashioned way to handle variable arguments. From the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) on `arguments`:

> If you're writing ES6 compatible code, then [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) should be preferred.

You're observing this strange behavior due to a quirk of ES6 arrow functions, detailed in the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (emphasis mine):

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although **without its own bindings to the `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target` keywords.**

Since you're using arrow functions, you should handle variable arguments with [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

```js
const noArguments = (...args) => {
  return args.length
}

const oneArgument = (...args) => {
  return args.length
}

const twoArguments = (...args) => {
  return args.length
}

console.log(noArguments());       // 0
console.log(oneArgument(1));      // 1
console.log(twoArguments(1, 2));  // 2
```

Comment: Thank you for both helping me with my issue as well as pointing me in the direction of some resources I can learn to figure out why this is happening! I am still learning the intricacies of ES6 so this is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

That not how you pass arguments.
that how arguments works:

```js
const myFunc = (...args) => {
  return args.length
};

console.log(myFunc(1,2,3,4))
console.log(myFunc())
```

Comment: @NicholasTower if you want to use arguments input from function that how it works.

Comment: I think you're using "arguments" as an english word. I was pointing out (in my deleted comment) that they're referring to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Comment: "this" is something else, it has nothing to do with arguments.
And it works different on arrow function/function from class/block function.

Comment: lol, good one. I talk about how you're mixing up english words and special javascript objects, and then you do it again. Very clever use of hyperbole.

Answer (score 0):

While this does not answer your question directly, `arguments` is not really used in modern Javascript besides when compiling and adapting es6 code to es5.

You should know that this keyword behaviour and its contents range from implementation to implementation.

You will be way better just using a rest parameter like this:

```
const myFunc = (...args) => args.forEach(console.log)
```

Please also note that accessing it with `myFunc.arguments` is deprecated and its support is not guaranteed.